# Subversion (SVN) log commands for a hotcopy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I've received a SVN hotcopy from a friend.  I only need to access the history of commits and edits (svn log).

I'm using Ubuntu and I don't have access to the internet.

How can I access the log if I'm pointing at the root directory where the .svn hidden folder is?

I need to do this from command line if possible.

I'm new to SVN so apologies if this is obvious.

Comment: If you have received a hotcopy from the SVN server you can access the repository via file access like `svn list file:///Path/To/The/Hotcopy` ...

Answer (score 0):

Unlike distributed version control systems such as Git and Mercurial, Subversion does not store past revisions locally. All you have are the checked out sources and a “pristine” — that is, unmodified — copy of them. If you cannot connect to the Subversion server, commands such as `svn log` or  `svn blame` won’t work, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

The *hotcopy* in Subversion terms means a [repository hot backup](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/hotcopy/). It is a fully functional repository that should reside on the SVN server. Therefore, if you actually have the hotcopy, you need to put or import the repository into your SVN server (e.g. VisualSVN Server) and access it via HTTP(S) with your favorite Subversion client (TortoiseSVN, I guess).

You can also skip the import and access the repository with the SVN client directly via the file:/// access protocol. For example, right-click the hotcopy in Windows File Explorer and select the **SVN Checkout** command.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by having my friend export out a dump file instead.
Steps:
1.  svnadmin create     //on a new empty folder
2.  svnadmin load 'folder just created' < 'full link to dump file'
3.  create an empty folder and browse to it in command prompt.
4.  svn co 'location dump loaded to' .   //*where . is the 2nd empty dir created.

Thanks for all your help.